# remove last values in column if they are identical

Tags: excel, vba

As I am not familiar with Excel VBA, this might be a standard question though I did not find a similar question.

I have a large number of columns K which are either empty or they end at the same row R (this is smaller than 65000).
For much of the (unsorted) nonempty columns the last r rows (row R-r+1, R-r+2, R-r+3, ..., R) have the same value.
Then, I want to delete the value of the last r-1 rows, and keep the value in row R-r+1.
So I want to put the following 'raw' code in Excel VBA:

```
find K and R by determining range of sheet
for k=1:K
    if cell(R,k)<>empty
        r=1;
        while cell(R-r,k)==cell(R,k)
            r=r+1;
        end
        cell(R-r+2,k) = '', cell(R-r+3,k) = '', ..., cell(R,k) = '';
    end
end
```

For instance, if the input of column k is

```
4
3
3
8
4
8
8
8
8
```

then after execution of the macro the output is

```
4
3
3
8
4
8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub ColumnCleaner()
    Dim col As Range, K As Long
    Dim cl As Range, N As Long, NN As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
        K = col.Column
        If wf.CountA(col) <> 0 Then
            NN = Cells(Rows.Count, K).End(xlUp).Row
            For N = NN To 2 Step -1
                If Cells(N, K).Value = Cells(N - 1, K).Value Then
                    Cells(N, K).Clear
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next N
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```